# Get and put event google calender

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a website to manage my colleague's  work load (you know assign stuff to them).
I want to use Google calendar to know their free times. Is it possible to get their events from Google calendar and then send mine? (to prevent any possible overlaps)

My language is PHP btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

There a [Simple example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php) for using the calendar API.